# Cannot deserialize the current JSON objectT into type because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Im having issues trying to desearilize my json array its structure is like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "entityGraph": {
      "shipmentKey": 1,
      "shipmentId": "1",
      "autoRateOn": true,
      "billByCompanyKey": 1,
      "billingNotes": "",
      "billToCustomerKey": 1,
      "bookedBy": null,
      "bookedFor": 0,
      "bookedForUserKey": null,
      "cargoValue": 0,
      "contactKey": 1,
      "contactNote": "",
      "createdBy": 1,
      "createdOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
      "customerKey": 1,
      "equipmentTypeKey": 1,
      "hasClaims": false,
      "invoiceNotes": "",
      "isHazmat": false,
      "isTeamRequired": false,
      "originalPaperworkReceivedOn": null,
      "paymentStatus": 0,
      "preloadedTrailerKey": null,
      "ratePlanKey": null,
      "reeferMode": 0,
      "reeferTemperature": 0,
      "referenceId1": "1",
      "referenceId2": "1",
      "referenceId3": "1",
      "referenceId4": "1",
      "referenceId5": "",
      "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxX00=",
      "status": 1,
      "updatedBy": 1,
      "updatedOn": "2022-10-03T16:41:23.260Z",
      "locContact": {
        "contactKey": 1,
        "anniversaryDate": null,
        "contactGKey": null,
        "createdOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
        "dateOfBirth": null,
        "emailAddress": "",
        "firstName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "middleName": "",
        "phoneExt1": "",
        "phoneExt2": "",
        "phoneExt3": "",
        "phoneNumber1": "",
        "phoneNumber2": "",
        "phoneNumber3": "",
        "phoneType1": 0,
        "phoneType2": 0,
        "phoneType3": 0,
        "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxXcs=",
        "title": "",
        "updatedOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
        "webSite": "",
        "validationErrors": [

        ]
      },
      "dspShipmentItems": [
        {
          "shipmentItemKey": 1,
          "description": "",
          "fromShipmentStopKey": 1,
          "goodsKey": 1,
          "ordinal": 1,
          "palletsCount": 0,
          "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxXc0=",
          "shipmentKey": 1,
          "toShipmentStopKey": 1,
          "unitsCount": 0,
          "volume": 0,
          "weight": 1,
          "validationErrors": [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "dspShipmentStops": [
        {
          "shipmentStopKey": 1,
          "addressKey": 1,
          "appointmentReference": "",
          "arrivedOnLocal": "2022-09-30T12:00:00.000Z",
          "arriveOnLocal": "2022-09-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "contactKey": 1,
          "departedOnLocal": "2022-09-30T13:00:00.000Z",
          "directionsNotes": "",
          "dispatcherNotes": "",
          "driverNotes": "",
          "drivingDistance": 0,
          "geocodeInfoString": "",
          "hoursOfOperation": "",
          "isAppointmentRequired": false,
          "isAppointmentSet": false,
          "isDropAndHook": false,
          "lateWhenAfterLocal": "2022-09-28T23:59:00.000Z",
          "locationKey": 1,
          "referenceId1": "",
          "routeInfoString": "",
          "routeKey": null,
          "shipmentKey": 1,
          "stopNumber": 1,
          "tripKey": 1,
          "tripStopKey": 1,
          "type": 0,
          "locAddress": {
            "addressKey": 1,
            "address1": "",
            "address2": "",
            "addressGKey": null,
            "administrativeArea": "",
            "company": "",
            "countryKey": 1,
            "createdOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "geocodingPrecision": 3,
            "latitude": 1,
            "longitude": -1,
            "municipality": "",
            "placedOn": "",
            "postalCode": "1",
            "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxXcg=",
            "timeZoneKey": null,
            "updatedOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "verificationStatus": 2,
            "validationErrors": [

            ]
          },
          "locContact": {
            "contactKey": 1,
            "anniversaryDate": null,
            "contactGKey": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "dateOfBirth": null,
            "emailAddress": "",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "middleName": "",
            "phoneExt1": "",
            "phoneExt2": "",
            "phoneExt3": "",
            "phoneNumber1": "0000000000",
            "phoneNumber2": "",
            "phoneNumber3": "",
            "phoneType1": 0,
            "phoneType2": 0,
            "phoneType3": 0,
            "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxXco=",
            "title": "",
            "updatedOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "webSite": "",
            "validationErrors": [

            ]
          },
          "validationErrors": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "shipmentStopKey": 1,
          "addressKey": 1,
          "appointmentReference": "",
          "arrivedOnLocal": "2022-10-03T09:00:00.000Z",
          "arriveOnLocal": "2022-10-03T00:00:00.000Z",
          "contactKey": 1,
          "departedOnLocal": "2022-10-03T10:00:00.000Z",
          "directionsNotes": "",
          "dispatcherNotes": "",
          "driverNotes": "",
          "drivingDistance": 1,
          "geocodeInfoString": "",
          "hoursOfOperation": "",
          "isAppointmentRequired": false,
          "isAppointmentSet": false,
          "isDropAndHook": false,
          "lateWhenAfterLocal": "2022-10-03T23:59:00.000Z",
          "locationKey": 1,
          "referenceId1": "",
          "routeInfoString": "",
          "routeKey": null,
          "shipmentKey": 1,
          "stopNumber": 2,
          "tripKey": 1,
          "tripStopKey": 1,
          "type": 1,
          "locAddress": {
            "addressKey": 1,
            "address1": "",
            "address2": "",
            "addressGKey": null,
            "administrativeArea": "",
            "company": "",
            "countryKey": 1,
            "createdOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "geocodingPrecision": 3,
            "latitude": 1,
            "longitude": -1,
            "municipality": "",
            "placedOn": "",
            "postalCode": "1",
            "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxXcc=",
            "timeZoneKey": null,
            "updatedOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "verificationStatus": 2,
            "validationErrors": [

            ]
          },
          "locContact": {
            "contactKey": 1,
            "anniversaryDate": null,
            "contactGKey": null,
            "createdOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "dateOfBirth": null,
            "emailAddress": "",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "middleName": "",
            "phoneExt1": "",
            "phoneExt2": "",
            "phoneExt3": "",
            "phoneNumber1": "0000000000",
            "phoneNumber2": "",
            "phoneNumber3": "",
            "phoneType1": 0,
            "phoneType2": 0,
            "phoneType3": 0,
            "rowVersion": "AAAAAAAxXck=",
            "title": "",
            "updatedOn": "2022-10-03T15:41:35.980Z",
            "webSite": "",
            "validationErrors": [

            ]
          },
          "validationErrors": [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "rnpShipmentRevenues": [
        {
          "shipmentRevenueKey": 1,
          "adjustedRevenueAmount": 1,
          "description": "",
          "isCalculatedFromRatePlan": false,
          "isInvoiced": true,
          "isPosted": true,
          "isUsedForPercentageBasedPay": true,
          "ordinal": 1,
          "paymentTypeKey": 1,
          "quantity": 1,
          "rateAmount": 1,
          "revenueAmount": 1,
          "shipmentKey": 1,
          "validationErrors": [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "validationErrors": [

      ]
    },
    "notes": null,
    "documents": null,
    "lookupCache": null,
    "validationResult": false,
    "lock": null
  },
  "url": "",
  "serverTime": "2022-10-03T16:44:26.959Z",
  "timeTook": "00:00:00.2812942",
  "error": null
}
```

The way to desearilize was first organize my json in [jsoneditoronline.org](https://jsoneditoronline.org) and create the class in [json2charp](https://json2csharp.com/) the result of the class was like this

```
 public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("entityGraph")]
    public List<EntityGraph> EntityGraph { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("notes")]
    public object Notes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("documents")]
    public object Documents { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lookupCache")]
    public object LookupCache { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationResult")]
    public bool ValidationResult { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lock")]
    public object Lock { get; set; }
}   

public class DspShipmentItem
{
    [JsonProperty("shipmentItemKey")]
    public int ShipmentItemKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fromShipmentStopKey")]
    public int FromShipmentStopKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("goodsKey")]
    public int GoodsKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ordinal")]
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("palletsCount")]
    public int PalletsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowVersion")]
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipmentKey")]
    public int ShipmentKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("toShipmentStopKey")]
    public int ToShipmentStopKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unitsCount")]
    public int UnitsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("volume")]
    public int Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weight")]
    public int Weight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationErrors")]
    public List<object> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}


public class DspShipmentStop
{
    [JsonProperty("shipmentStopKey")]
    public int ShipmentStopKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("addressKey")]
    public int AddressKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("appointmentReference")]
    public string AppointmentReference { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("arrivedOnLocal")]
    public object ArrivedOnLocal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("arriveOnLocal")]
    public DateTime ArriveOnLocal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contactKey")]
    public int ContactKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("departedOnLocal")]
    public object DepartedOnLocal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("directionsNotes")]
    public string DirectionsNotes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dispatcherNotes")]
    public string DispatcherNotes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("driverNotes")]
    public string DriverNotes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("drivingDistance")]
    public double DrivingDistance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("geocodeInfoString")]
    public string GeocodeInfoString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hoursOfOperation")]
    public string HoursOfOperation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isAppointmentRequired")]
    public bool IsAppointmentRequired { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isAppointmentSet")]
    public bool IsAppointmentSet { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isDropAndHook")]
    public bool IsDropAndHook { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lateWhenAfterLocal")]
    public DateTime LateWhenAfterLocal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locationKey")]
    public int LocationKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("referenceId1")]
    public string ReferenceId1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("routeInfoString")]
    public string RouteInfoString { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("routeKey")]
    public object RouteKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipmentKey")]
    public int ShipmentKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stopNumber")]
    public int StopNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tripKey")]
    public object TripKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tripStopKey")]
    public object TripStopKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locAddress")]
    public LocAddress LocAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locContact")]
    public LocContact LocContact { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationErrors")]
    public List<object> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}

public class EntityGraph
{
    [JsonProperty("shipmentKey")]
    public int ShipmentKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipmentId")]
    public string ShipmentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("autoRateOn")]
    public bool AutoRateOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("billByCompanyKey")]
    public int BillByCompanyKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("billingNotes")]
    public string BillingNotes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("billToCustomerKey")]
    public int BillToCustomerKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bookedBy")]
    public object BookedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bookedFor")]
    public int BookedFor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bookedForUserKey")]
    public object BookedForUserKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cargoValue")]
    public int CargoValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contactKey")]
    public int ContactKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contactNote")]
    public string ContactNote { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdBy")]
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customerKey")]
    public int CustomerKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("equipmentTypeKey")]
    public int EquipmentTypeKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hasClaims")]
    public bool HasClaims { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("invoiceNotes")]
    public string InvoiceNotes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isHazmat")]
    public bool IsHazmat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isTeamRequired")]
    public bool IsTeamRequired { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("originalPaperworkReceivedOn")]
    public object OriginalPaperworkReceivedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("paymentStatus")]
    public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("preloadedTrailerKey")]
    public object PreloadedTrailerKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ratePlanKey")]
    public object RatePlanKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reeferMode")]
    public int ReeferMode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reeferTemperature")]
    public int ReeferTemperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("referenceId1")]
    public string ReferenceId1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("referenceId2")]
    public string ReferenceId2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("referenceId3")]
    public string ReferenceId3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("referenceId4")]
    public string ReferenceId4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("referenceId5")]
    public string ReferenceId5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowVersion")]
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updatedBy")]
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updatedOn")]
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locContact")]
    public LocContact LocContact { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dspShipmentItems")]
    public List<RootDspShipmentItem> DspShipmentItems { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dspShipmentStops")]
    public List<RootDspShipmentStop> DspShipmentStops { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rnpShipmentRevenues")]
    public List<RootRnpShipmentRevenue> RnpShipmentRevenues { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationErrors")]
    public List<object> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}

public class LocAddress
{
    [JsonProperty("addressKey")]
    public int AddressKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("addressGKey")]
    public object AddressGKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("administrativeArea")]
    public string AdministrativeArea { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("countryKey")]
    public int CountryKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("geocodingPrecision")]
    public int GeocodingPrecision { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("municipality")]
    public string Municipality { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("placedOn")]
    public string PlacedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postalCode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowVersion")]
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeZoneKey")]
    public object TimeZoneKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updatedOn")]
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("verificationStatus")]
    public int VerificationStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationErrors")]
    public List<object> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}

public class LocContact
{
    [JsonProperty("contactKey")]
    public int ContactKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("anniversaryDate")]
    public object AnniversaryDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contactGKey")]
    public object ContactGKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")]
    public object DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("middleName")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneExt1")]
    public string PhoneExt1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneExt2")]
    public string PhoneExt2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneExt3")]
    public string PhoneExt3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneNumber1")]
    public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneNumber2")]
    public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneNumber3")]
    public string PhoneNumber3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneType1")]
    public int PhoneType1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneType2")]
    public int PhoneType2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneType3")]
    public int PhoneType3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rowVersion")]
    public string RowVersion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updatedOn")]
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("webSite")]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationErrors")]
    public List<object> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}


public class RnpShipmentRevenue
{
    [JsonProperty("shipmentRevenueKey")]
    public int ShipmentRevenueKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("adjustedRevenueAmount")]
    public int AdjustedRevenueAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isCalculatedFromRatePlan")]
    public bool IsCalculatedFromRatePlan { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isInvoiced")]
    public bool IsInvoiced { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isPosted")]
    public bool IsPosted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isUsedForPercentageBasedPay")]
    public bool IsUsedForPercentageBasedPay { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ordinal")]
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("paymentTypeKey")]
    public int PaymentTypeKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rateAmount")]
    public int RateAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("revenueAmount")]
    public int RevenueAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipmentKey")]
    public int ShipmentKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("validationErrors")]
    public List<object> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("serverTime")]
    public DateTime ServerTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeTook")]
    public string TimeTook { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public object Error { get; set; }
}
```

I think the error must be in the structure because inside the jsonproperty shipments are arrays inside and i think it must be another class Root but i'm not pretty sure

Comment: What code do you use to deserialize? And recheck the json you posted, it is invalid now.

Comment: Well, look at your json. You should be able to easily identify where json arrays occur. Then look at the data type you deserialize into (look at the code you wrote for the deserialization), and check whether the type itself and the properties of this type (and the types of the properties of the type...) adhere to the json data structure...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace If for example in the JSON is the property ShipmentsStops and inside has two arrays with more data how can i declare in csharp so when it desearilize it include this 2 array i say it because this two array doesn't have a name to identify

Comment: You haven't even given us the full JSON structure so how can we possibly help?

Comment: @DavidG i already made the edits, my intention was to avoid post the complete cause it was to big sorry

Comment: Look, we are trying to help and you are not giving us your actual code. For a start, the JSON you show here is invalid, the 4th line is nonsense. Next, your classes assume `Root.Data` is an array when it is not in the JSON. Same goes for `Data.EntityGraph`. I'm sure there are more problems but I gave us looking.

Comment: @itsFerxis Json you posted still is not valid , there are a lot of bugs like this   "shipmentKey": ,  .  I don't think that it is because you were trying to make json smaller.  How are you going to deserialize it?

Comment: Sorry for all the troubles, im still new in post here in stack and but i run the json and its already valid Again apologize my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the property Data, instead of list use just Data

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
   .....
}
```

and fix the property EntityGraph, instead of list use just EntityGraph

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("entityGraph")]
    public EntityGraph EntityGraph { get; set; }
 .....
}
```

and fix these properties inside of EntityGraph class

```
    [JsonProperty("dspShipmentItems")]
    public List<DspShipmentItem> DspShipmentItems { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dspShipmentStops")]
    public List<DspShipmentStop> DspShipmentStops { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rnpShipmentRevenues")]
    public List<RnpShipmentRevenue> RnpShipmentRevenues { get; set; }

           // instead of 

//  [JsonProperty("dspShipmentItems")]
//  public List<RootDspShipmentItem> DspShipmentItems { get; set; }
//
//  [JsonProperty("dspShipmentStops")]
//  public List<RootDspShipmentStop> DspShipmentStops { get; set; }
//
//  [JsonProperty("rnpShipmentRevenues")]
//  public List<RootRnpShipmentRevenue> RnpShipmentRevenues { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks it was solved! I appreciate a lot for your time and advice!